# TypeScript curious error with generics and inheritance. What's wrong?

Tags: generics, inheritance, typescript

I am trying to build some base classes for my current project. Currenty I am getting this compiler error:

Type 'IConcreteScope' does not satisfy the constraint 'IEntityScope' for type parameter 'TScope extends IEntityScope'.

When I try to run this code:

```
// scope 
export interface IScope {
    context: any;
}
export class ContextBase<TScope extends IScope> {
    scope: TScope;
} 
// entity
export interface IEntity {
    id: string;
}
export interface IEntityScope<TEntity extends IEntity> extends IScope {
    entity: TEntity;    
}
export class EntityContextBase<TEntity extends IEntity, TScope extends IEntityScope<TEntity>> {
    operation(entity: TEntity) {...}    
}
// concrete 
export interface IConcreteEntity extends IEntity {
    name: string;
}
export interface IConcreteScope extends IEntityScope<IConcreteEntity> {
    someprop: boolean;
}
// this is the problem: EntityContextBase<IConcreteEntity,IConcreteScope>
export class ConcretContext extends EntityContextBase<IConcreteEntity,IConcreteScope> {

}
```

Here the link to the TypeScript playground [code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=//%20scope%20%0Aexport%20interface%20IScope%20%7B%0A%09context%3a%20any;%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20ContextBase%3CTScope%20extends%20IScope%3E%20%7B%0A%09scope%3a%20TScope;%0A%7D%20%0A%0A//%20entity%0Aexport%20interface%20IEntity%20%7B%0A%09id%3a%20string;%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20interface%20IEntityScope%3CTEntity%20extends%20IEntity%3E%20extends%20IScope%20%7B%0A%09entity%3a%20TEntity;%20%09%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20EntityContextBase%3CTEntity%20extends%20IEntity,%20TScope%20extends%20IEntityScope%3CTEntity%3E%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09%0A%7D%0A%0A//%20concrete%20%0Aexport%20interface%20IConcreteEntity%20extends%20IEntity%20%7B%0A%09name%3a%20string;%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20interface%20IConcreteScope%20extends%20IEntityScope%3CIConcreteEntity%3E%20%7B%0A%09selected%3a%20boolean;%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20ConcretContext%20extends%20EntityContextBase%3CIConcreteEntity,IConcreteScope%3E%20%7B%0A%09%0A%7D%20%0A%0A)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the code is actually right, and the compiler is getting confused somewhere in EntityContextBase.  Like it loses track of the two TEntitys being the same thing.  That is not an easy structure to comprehend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine; it's a bug in the compiler. This compiles without error in the latest sources from the develop branch.